# Submission time removal

Tags: cognito-forms, date

I am looking for a way to remove the submission date/time from the items seen when looking at entries in the Cognito forms. I have multiple employees that I am ok with them working after hours but the guys upstairs don't like to see it so I need the form to not keep track of when they submit the form. Is this possible? I have tried to uncheck it under the build settings but it just rechecks it every time I refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

All entries have system metadata that can not be deleted or changed including DateSubmitted, DateCreated and DateUpdated.

While you can't delete these fields entirely, you can certainly remove them from the Entries view. First click Columns then uncheck the fields, then **click the Save button to the right of the Filter button**. When you refresh you page they will not show.